# Cannot deserialize xml with same node names

Tags: c#, xml, .net-6.0

we are getting a XML file from a 3rd party service and I need to parse it into an object. The root element is `table` which contains several `row`s. And each row has multiple `column`s. For now I just want to treat any column value as `nullable string`.

Xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
    <row>
        <column>abc</column>
        <column>def</column>
        <column>ghi</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>jkl</column>
        <column>mno</column>
        <column>pqr</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column></column>
        <column></column>
        <column></column>
    </row>
</table>
```

I have created these classes to map the data into:

```cs
[Serializable, XmlRoot("table")]
public class XmlDoc
{
    [XmlArrayItem("row")]
    public XmlDocRow[] Rows { get; set; } = Array.Empty<XmlDocRow>();
}

public class XmlDocRow
{
    [XmlArrayItem("column")]
    public string?[] Columns { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string?>();
}
```

However when I try to de-serialize this using the following code, it won't work

```cs
using System.Xml.Serialization;
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDoc));
var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Downloads\file.xml");
var data = (XmlDoc)xml.Deserialize(reader);
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(data);
reader.Close();
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.WriteLine(data.Rows);
Console.WriteLine(data.Rows.First());

// outputs
XmlDoc
XmlDocRow[]
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\console\Program.cs:line 10
```

My expectation would have been to have 3 items in the Rows array, each in turn having 3 nullable strings in the Columns array. Can somebody please hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Should be : [XmlElement("row")] and [XmlElement ("column")]

Comment: This is it! Thank you, unfortunately I cannot accept as answer a comment to this question. Therefore I at least upvoted it.